# JTextArea Transfer Focus

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextarea, keylistener

I'm trying to transfer focus from one JTextArea to another when the user hits tab.
Currently I'm using this code:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {                  
        if(e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB){
            enterTextArea.transferFocus();
        }               
}
```

This appears to work - the focus moves and you type in the next JTextArea - but actually the text stills gets appened to the first TextArea, meaning that performing a getText() on the second TextArea just returns `""`.

How do I make the text typed go to the second JTextArea rather than just get appended to the first?

**EDIT:** On further inspection this behavior was caused by a separate bug. No further help needed.

Comment: TAB is built_in KeyEvent in API, is common keys short_cut, valid for lot of aplication based on various  programming languages, don't to confuse the users

Answer (score 0):

You can just transfer the text from 1 to 2 by using getText on the first one.

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {                  
    if(e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB){
        enterTextArea.transferFocus();
        String firstField = textField1.getText();
        secondField.setText(firstField);
    }               
}
```

That way it will save from the first text area, and put it into the second one.

Hope this helps!